# pandas delete a cell and shift up the column

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, shift

I am using pandas with python.
I have a column in which the first value is zero. 
There are other zeros as well in the column but i don't want to delete them as well.
I want to delete this cell and move the column up by 1 position.
If it is easy i can make the first Zero as an empty cell and then delete but i cant find anything just to delete a specific cell and move the rest of the column up. 
SO far i have tried help from existing stack overflow and quora plus github etc but i cant see anything i am looking for.

Comment: What about `df['A'] = df['A'].shift(-1)` ?

Comment: If you shift the column up, what would you like for the last value in the column?

Comment: But then get NaN in last value.

Comment: @jezrael. Thank you so much. I spent a day just to get this to work. Now i have the last element as an empty cell which i can replace by a zero later. Thanks again let me try the other one also and then i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) first and then replace last `NaN` value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

If no `NaN`s only use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `NaN`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].shift(-1).fillna('AAA')
print (df)
     A  B  C  D  E  F
0    b  4  7  1  5  a
1    c  5  8  3  3  a
2    d  4  9  5  6  a
3    e  5  4  7  9  b
4    f  5  2  1  2  b
5  AAA  4  3  0  4  b
```

If possible some `NaN`s in column then set last value by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) function return position of column `A`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].shift(-1)
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('A')] = 'AAA'
print (df)
     A  B  C  D  E  F
0    b  4  7  1  5  a
1    c  5  8  3  3  a
2    d  4  9  5  6  a
3    e  5  4  7  9  b
4    f  5  2  1  2  b
5  AAA  4  3  0  4  b
```